# How can i integrate C# code into an existing Javascript website (Angular)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, mono, blazor

We have a large ecosystem of Javascript websites, actually Angular, that we don't plan to rewrite in c# any time soon. So the goal here is to be able to use a vendor dll in our javascript to add new features. This is a proprietary system, we don't have any alternative, either we use their dll, either we don't have the feature. I'm putting a lot of hope in webassembly here because this looked like the silver bullet to use that dll without having to rewrite the whole project in a new language.

Problem: all the examples I can find are more about using Blazor to write a website or call javascript from Blazor, I can't find anything to include some ad-hoc C# code into an existing project. I would have thought it would be a great use case though because being able to leverage C# threadpool on a webpage sounds pretty good to me!

Anyone has done something similar or know some examples/tutorials I could follow?

Comment: The thing is C# is server code, so it can only run on a server. Angular compiled to HTML/CSS/Javascript code, which run on web browser. Web browsers restrict the system resource a website javascript code can access for security reasons. So the answer to your question is no, at least as I know of

Comment: Are you looking for a way to compile C# to wasm without Blazor? See https://www.mono-project.com/news/2018/01/16/mono-static-webassembly-compilation/

Comment: @Tuan: what do you mean by "C# is server code" exactly?

Comment: @itminus: not exactly. I want to consume C# code from an existing javascript page, without having to overhaul the whole website.

Comment: @Gregfr since we can compile C# into wasm+dll,  we can consume wasm+dll via js. See [the factorial_submit function that consumes C# demo](view-source:http://www.hipbyte.com/~lrz/mono-wasm-hello/?input=61&Submit=Calculate)

Comment: @itminus: interesting, do you know where is the code source maybe?

Comment: @Gregfr See https://github.com/migueldeicaza/mono-wasm/blob/master/sample/hello2/index.html

Comment: Whatever the C# code is you want to run can't you have it run on the server rather than browser and expose it's functionality over a REST API that your client side Angular apps can call, or must the C# code run in the browser?

Comment: @Paul: it needs to run on the client side. There's no way around that. It would be an easy solution otherwise ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Tuan says Angular and C# don't really live together in the way you suggest.

I would say there are 2 separate approaches here.

1. Have an C#.NET MVC app but adjust the routing so the Angular App Handles some pages and the .NET app handles others. This is OK but there are so many pitfalls such as the fact that you can not share bundled CSS and JS or maintain the structure of your Angular controllers (amongst others).
2. A better way would be keep your lovely Angular app the way it is but have a separate Web API application/project and use the angular app to call the dll (reference in the project) within the correct context as a REST API (via a simple POST or GET call).

It's not too clear exactly what you want to do when you say "... able to use a vendor dll in our javascript to add new features ..." but you can find info on writing and implementing C# as a Web API in .NET core here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: thx for your answer. I should have added that our Angular apps are packaged in nwjs to run on the desktop of the user. I thought of option #2, but the problem is that this dll needs to be runned on the user desktop because it will interface with another app he runs. So the only option i'm seeing is spawn a C# server on the user desktop, for my Angular apps  to talk to. I don't really like this solution, but i don't see any other way.

Comment: I understand and having it run as a desktop app is difficult as that is not the way Angular is designed. You could consider having an AngularJS version of the App which would slot better into C# and MVC but of course you wouldn't have the benifits of "true" Angular such as Type Script.